# Is it possible to strum (with a pick) separated strings?

Tags: guitar, technique, picking

There is a [song](http://www.ultimate-guitar.com/tabs/s/seether/broken_ver2_tab.htm) I am trying to learn and the problem is that the guitarist plays the first and fourth strings together. I know this is easily possible if you are finger picking, but I am not really a huge fan of finger picking. Is there any way to do this with a pick, or am I just going to have to get used to it?

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use a pick, you basically have two options:

1. Use the pick-and-fingers method (which is what I do most of the time).  I hold the pick with my thumb and index finger and pick the low string while I use my middle and ring finger to pick other, higher strings.
2. Use your left (fingerboard) hand to mute the strings in between the two you want to play, and strum as ususal.  The only notes you'll hear are the two un-muted strings, but the muted strings will provide a percussive sound that you may like or not.

But looking at the tab you linked to, I'd definitely play that particular tune fingerstyle.

Comment: +1, I always use both of these methods. Also, if a tune has many parts where many strings should be plucked at once, consider playing it with your fingers.

Answer (score 0):

You could always fret the first and fourth strings while muting the strings between and then strum.. would that give the effect you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

i would tend to use a technique which is a mixture between alternate picking and flatpicking.

it uses up and down strokes, while bouncing between the strings i want to hit.

it takes quite a bit of practice, i got it by playing rhythm and lead guitar with very similar picking techniques for both, i then got used to playing specific strings without needing to think about it too much.

Answer (score -2):

**Hybrid Picking**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_picking

Comment: Please extend this answer, a simple link should really have been given as a comment to the question using the "add comment" button directly beneath the question.

Comment: To extend what @DRL said, if the link breaks the answer will be worthless. By providing some content besides the link the answer would still have some value.